# WSO2 EI 6.3.0 - timezone issue

Tags: wso2

I have issue with dataservices in EI6.3.0 related to timezone. I am in: Central European Time (CET) +0100 UTC (Daylight Saving Time). When I invoke *"select sysdate from dual"* I still getting wrong time - 1 hour after my current time. For example when is 9.00 PM I get response 10.00 PM. I have WSO2 AS 5.2.1 and there is no issue with time. I tried serveral solution like :
-Ddss.legacy.timezone.mode=true but none of them is working. Can you help me?

Comment: Hi, any luck solving your problem? Based on your description is was the database? :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding: Ddss.legacy.timezone.mode=true to both configuration:
 
...\wso2ei-6.3.0\bin\integrator.bat
 
...\wso2ei-6.3.0\yajsw-stable-11.11\conf\wrapper.conf
 
Previously I forgot to add this entry to wrapper.conf cause I run WSO2 as windows service.